# Hard-Drive Health Analysis - Western Digital Hard Drive (7200RPM, 320GB)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, 64-bit

What is the best tool for determining the health of an internal hard drive?  I have a Western Digital 320GB at 7200 RPM.  The OS currently installed on it (a fresh install) is Windows 7 Professional 64-Bit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try [HDTune](http://www.hdtune.com/), which has a 15-day free trial.

> HD Tune is a hard disk utility with many functions. It can be used to measure the drive's performance, scan for errors, check the health status (S.M.A.R.T.), securely erase all data and much more.

[image]